# Declaring a function pointer returning an array

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

For practice, I'm trying to :

Declare `fubar` to be a pointer to a function that takes a pointer to a `char` and returns a pointer to an array of 24 elements where each element is a pointer to a `struct foo`.

My logic is:

-fubar is a pointer to a function taking a char pointer:
 `(*fubar)(char*)`

-...returning a pointer to an array of 24 elems of where each elem is a struct foo:

`(struct foo *)(*fubar)(char*)[24]`

Is my logic correct?

Comment: No. The parentheses make a big difference. It should be `struct foo* (*fubar)(char*)[24]` for this to be valid syntax.

Comment: Do you know cdecl (http://www.cdecl.org/)?

Comment: Yes I do know cdecl but it was saying syntax error but I didnt know why.

Comment: `(struct foo *)` is a typecast, which makes no sense in this case. You could have tried to remove the parentheses: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=struct+foo+*%28*fubar%29%28char*%29[24] and then it's not a syntax error anymore.

Comment: @mch ahhhh i see! Thanks for adding that comment, I think I'm finally understanding it more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fixing the syntax error and removing the parentheses around `struct foo *`,

```
struct foo* (*fubar)(char*)[24]
```

...the one part that you got wrong is that it actually returns an array *of* pointers, not a pointer to an array. In order to declare a pointer to the array, you need an extra set of parentheses:

```
struct foo (*(*fubar)(char*))[24]
```

You can pretend that that the star belongs to an identifier (i.e., the name of the array) inside the parentheses.

Comment: quick question: will removing the outer parentheses change the statement? 
Is `struct foo *(*fubar)(char*)[24]` the same?

Comment: @Penu Like I said, the parentheses matter. Fixing the syntax error leads to the form you just described, which returns an array of pointers. The parentheses change the *binding* of complex declarators.

Comment: Thanks. I've been thinking but should the answer in fact be: `struct foo *(*(*fubar)(char*))[24]`

Comment: @penu No, that returns a pointer to an array of pointers. I was presenting syntax that demonstrates what it would look like if your understanding had been correct.

Answer (score 1):

Functions never return arrays, they may return a pointer (conventionally to the first cell of an array), since as return value or as argument an array *decays* to a pointer.

So, declare with a `typedef` the signature of your function:

```
typedef struct foo** funsig_t(char*);
```

<sup>notice that if you omit the `typedef` you would declare a *function* `funsig_t` of the *desired signature*.</sup>

then declare a pointer using that typedef:

```
funsig_t* fubar;
```