# c assign a outer function function to a variable

Tags: c, functional-programming, function-pointers

I have a struct containing amongst other things a function variable that I would like to assign a function to that is itself visible on the global level, like so:

```
typedef struct HashMap{
    struct LinkedList** datapointers;
    int key_space;
    int* (*hash_function)(const char*);
}HashMap;
unsigned int hashfunction(const char* input){
    int i=0;
    int hash=0;
    while(input[i]){
        hash=hash+input[i]; 
        i++;
    }
    return hash;
}
//create a new hashmap 
HashMap* create_hashmap(int key_space){
    HashMap *hm = malloc (sizeof(HashMap));
    hm->datapointers = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList)*key_space); //array of linked lists 
    hm->key_space=key_space; 
    for(int i=0;i<key_space;i++){ //initalize to NULL 
        hm->datapointers[i]=NULL;
    }
    hm->hash_function=*hashfunction;
    return hm;
}
```

now no matter what I do I keep getting invalid pointers or undeclared variables. Is there any way to get this to work right?

Thank you

Comment: what is the definition of LinkedList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should read like

```
hm->hash_function = hashfunction;
```

but, there is a mismatch.

the function pointer type is `int* (*hash_function)(const char*);`

but your function signature is

```
unsigned int hashfunction(const char* input)
```

IMO, it should be

1. `int* hashfunction(const char* input)` [need to modify function definition accordingly]

or

2. `unsigned int (*hash_function)(const char*);`

Comment: Ah yes that teaches me not to copy paste other pieces of code for signatures.

Answer (score 1):

You should code

```
  hm->hash_function = hashfunction;
```

also, your `hashfunction` has an incorrect signature. Define it as:

```
  int hashfunction(const char* input)
```

*without* the `unsigned`, and declare the field:

```
 int (*hash_function)(const char*);
```

BTW, you better understand what are [*closures*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29). You probably should consider adding some client data to every function used *indirectly*. You could for example add a field `void* client_data;` inside your `struct HashMap`. See also [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/263057/every-function-is-a-closure/263094#263094). Read more about [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

At last, I find much more readable to declare with a `typedef` the signature (used in pointers to function) like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27122203/841108).

Comment: that gives a warning assignment from inccompatible pointer type, is it ok to ignore this?

Answer (score 1):

I got a bunch of warning. Here's the modified code that doesn't give any warning:

```
typedef struct HashMap{
    struct LinkedList** datapointers;
    int key_space;
    int (*hash_function)(const char*);
}HashMap;
int hashfunction(const char* input){
    int i=0;
    int hash=0;
    while(input[i]){
        hash=hash+input[i]; 
        i++;
    }
    return hash;
}
//create a new hashmap 
HashMap* create_hashmap(int key_space){
    HashMap *hm = malloc (sizeof(HashMap));
    hm->datapointers = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList)*key_space); //array of linked lists 
    hm->key_space=key_space; 
    for(int i=0;i<key_space;i++){ //initalize to NULL 
        hm->datapointers[i]=NULL;
    }
    hm->hash_function=hashfunction;
    return hm;
}
```

Changes are:
1. The function pointer hash_function doesn't return int * but int.

2. The hashfunction now returns int instead of unsigned int.
3. While assigning hashfunction to hash_function, don't dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

```
The following is the correct code.
However, since the LinkedList is not defined in your posted code, 
it fails to compile.


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// where/what is the definition of LinkedList?

// define the HashMap struct
struct HashMap
{
    struct LinkedList** datapointers;
    int key_space;
    unsigned int (*hash_function)(const char*);
};

// prototypes
unsigned int hashfunction(const char*);
struct HashMap* create_hashmap(int);


unsigned int hashfunction(const char* input)
{
    int i=0;
    unsigned int hash=0;

    while(input[i])
    {
        hash += input[i];
        i++;
    } // end while

    return hash;
} // end function: hashfunction


//create a new hashmap
struct HashMap* create_hashmap(int key_space)
{
    // define an instance of the HashMap struct
    struct HashMap *hm = malloc (sizeof(struct HashMap));
    if( NULL == hm )
    { // then malloc failed
        perror( "malloc of HashMap failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // array of linked lists
    if( NULL == hm->datapointers = malloc(sizeof(LinkedList)*key_space) )
    { // then, malloc failed
        perror( "malloc of HashMap.datapointer failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, malloc successful

    // fill in fields of HashMap
    hm->key_space=key_space;
    memset( hm->datapointers, 0x00, sizeof(LinkedList*key_space) );
    hm->hash_function = &hashfunction;

    return hm;
} // end function: create_hashmap
```