# What does this code do ? C

Tags: c, signals

I'm trying to figure out what does this code do, and I could use some help.

```
int sethandler( void (*f)(int), int sigNo) {
    struct sigaction act;
    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(struct sigaction));
    act.sa_handler = f;
    if (-1==sigaction(sigNo, &act, NULL))
        return -1;
    return 0;
}

void sigchld_handler(int sig) {
    pid_t pid;
    for(;;)
    {
        pid=waitpid(0, NULL, WNOHANG);
        if(0==pid) return;
        if(0>=pid) {
            if(ECHILD==errno) return;
                ERR("waitpid:");
        }
    }
}
```

This is the function call in main:

```
if(sethandler(sigchld_handler, SIGCHLD)) 
    ERR("Setting parent SIGCHLD Error:");
```

`ERR` just prints out the type of error, and on which line it occurred, it's irrelevant to the question.

The following is what i'm confused about: 
Which function is called first `sethandler` or `sigchld_handler`?.
What does `(*f)(int)`mean?. 
And what does `act.sa_handler = f`do?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following is what i'm confused about: Which function is called first `sethandler` or `sigchld_handler`?

`sethandler` is the only function called directly in this code. The call to `sigaction` in `sethandler` may cause `sigchld_handler` to be called later, however.

> What does `(*f)(int)` mean?

`void (*f)(int)` is a pointer variable named `f`, pointing to a function which takes one `int` argument and returns `void`. (In this case, the function being pointed to is `sigchld_handler`.)

> And what does `act.sa_handler = f` do?

It assigns that pointer to `act.sa_handler`. This is used to register that function as a signal handler.

Comment: on which line in the `sethander` function does `sigchld_handler` function gets called ?

Comment: None of them. The function is not called; it is being registered as a signal handler.

Answer (score 2):

> What does `void (*f)(int)` mean?

It is the syntax to declare `f`  as a pointer to a function taking one `int` argument and not returning any result. I prefer to use a `typedef`  on the [function's signature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27122203/841108), for readability reasons.

You should read a good book on programming (e.g. [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) explains the interest of handling functions as [*first-class*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen) values)  and another good book about programming in C. You'll then [realize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29427906/841108) that C does [not](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/263094/40065) have genuine [closures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29), and that you need to use *conventions* about [callbacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29).

> what does `act.sa_handler = f;` do

It assigns to the member `sa_handler`  of structure `act` the function pointer `f`

You need to carefully read about signals. I suggest first read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) then read *carefully* [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) (the notion of *async-signal-safe-function* is tricky and important to understand) and  [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html)

<sup>(so several books are required to answer your questions. I gave the references, but you need to take weeks to read them)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the declaration of `sigaction`.

`f` is a pointer to a function int -> void.

`sa_handler` is en element in `sigaction` that is set to the pointer to the function.

As to which one is called first, that information is not in the code you posted.

Addition: `sethandler` called first